# Search Strings for particular sequence

Tags: c#, regex, string

fairly new to c#, im looking for a way to search a string for a particular sequence:

```
string mytext = "I want to find t56b45 in a string"
```

In the above example i would like to search mytext for the position of "t" but only when it is followed by any two numeric chars and a "b" followed by any two numeric chars. If i find a "t"+any two numeric values+"b"+any two numeric values then i would like to create a sub string up to that position ie. the result string will read "I want to find"

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: ... And what do you want to do if no match is found? `Regex.Match(mytext, @".*(?=t\d{2}b\d{2})")` appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @DanielA.White i managed to use the Regex similar manner to what PhilDulac  suggested, i shall post the code once i get back to my home desktop.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie thanks! used a variation of that, seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Regex`:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // \s : Matches a space
        // t : Exact match t
        // \d{2} : Any digit, 2 repetition
        // t : Exact match b
        // \d{2} : Any digit, 2 repetition
        var match = Regex.Match("I want to find t56b45 in a string", @".*(?=\st\d{2}b\d{2})");

        if(match.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("\"" + match.Value + "\"");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Nothing found.");
        // Outputs: "I want to find"
    }
}
```

Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kguwDW

Comment: Why are you looking for the start of the string, the other text, or spaces? Why not just search for the pattern being sought?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't need to check for the beginning of the string, but it needs to check for the space to exclude it from the resulting string.

Comment: Thanks @PhilDulac managed to use similar code and get it working. I shall post it later this evening, give me your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code i ended up using, seems to get the job done and ignore the case

```
 var tempmatch = Regex.Match(TempCleaned, "(?i)y[0-9]+(?i)z[0-9]+");

            if (tempmatch.Success)
            {
                //clean all text from YxxZxx

             string NewName = TempCleaned.Substring(0, tempmatch.Index -1);
```

Comment: Tried to check on http://regexr.com/ what your regex was doing and it came up a invalid. You might want to double check it to make sure you it's valid and reliable. It might just be something that's only supported by the .NET framework but it costs nothing to check.

Comment: @PhilDulac So the expression works as i wanted it to, i check regexr.com out and it flags the ?i as invalid. those are used to ignore case. I think it is something that is supported by .Net. Thanks for the heads up though!